# Android: Is it possible to set overlay on camera if we use this code below?

Tags: android, camera

```
Intent i = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

mFileUri = getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE);

i.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mFileUri);

startActivityForResult(i, CAMERA_CAPTURE_PHOTO_REQUEST_CODE);
```

I am trying to add a button on Camera Overlay, but most tutorials out there create a camera file that `extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback`.  While that way is great for implementing a custom camera, I realize you have to rebuild some buttons for taking photos. Please Correct me if I'm wrong.

I want to use the Android default camera buttons and just add an overlay view for one button on top. Is it possible to do that? Like `i.setOverlay(View v...);` or something like that. Any help will be grateful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to do that?

No, because that is not your app. That is somebody else's app. You cannot modify the UI of somebody else's app from your app.

Comment: Are you kidding? So Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE); is calling the android app camera. @.@, and NO!!!!

Comment: @tipsywacky: "Are you kidding?" -- no. "is calling the android app camera" -- not necessarily, if I understand you correctly. It will launch whichever activity exists on the device that supports your `Intent` structure and that the user chooses. That *may* be the device's built-in camera app. It may also be a third-party camera app that the user installed.